# Spring Boot with Struts Filter and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, struts2

I am migrating a Struts2 application to Spring Boot. I defined the `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` inside my Application boot class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClearApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClearApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ClearApplication.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    Collection<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    urlPatterns.add("/*");
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter struts = new StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter();
    registrationBean.setFilter(struts);
    registrationBean.setName("strutsFilter");
    registrationBean.setOrder(1);
    registrationBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
    return registrationBean;
  }
}
```

The `pom.xml` file configuration is below

```
<groupId>com.study.pack</groupId>
<artifactId>clear</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>clear</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
```

My action class has one simple Struts action and another json action

```
@Action(value = "welcome", results = { @Result(name = "success", location = "result.jsp") })
public String execute() {
    return "success";
}

@Action(value = "users", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = { "root", "userList" }) })
public String users() {
    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new User("Carl", "15", "M"));
    userList.add(new User("Rick", "30", "M"));
    userList.add(new User("Michonne", "26", "F"));
    return "success";
}
```

When, I am deploying the application on my local Tomcat server. I am able to access the action URLs

`http://localhost:8080/clear/welcome`

`http://localhost:8080/clear/users`

But, when I run the application in STS (or by using maven command), I am getting the standard struts error when accessing the same above URLs

> **There is no Action mapped for namespace [/clear] and action name [users] associated with context path [].**

The `application.properties` has the following properties

```
server.contextPath=/clear
server.port=8080
```

Am I missing any other configuration to get it working ?

**Update:**

As @Roman-C suggested, I checked the startup logs of tomcat server and the context path is identical.

**External Tomcat Server:**

```
[ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/clear]         : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

**Embedded Tomcat Server:**

```
[ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/clear]  : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

The application.properties lies within the folder

```
src/main/resources
```

Still No luck. Somehow the struts annotations are ignored I guess.

I have committed the source code in [GitHub](https://github.com/creativekarma/clear).

Comment: Bala, have you had any luck on this matter? Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, I did not.

Answer (score 2):

By default Spring Boot initializes the embedded tomcat to the root application context. So you can access your application from `/`.

The URL is mapped to the action by the action mapper. The default action mapper's implementation is in [`DefaultActionMapper`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/DefaultActionMapper.html) that parses the URL and extracts action name and namespace. The path before the last slash after the context path is a namespace, the action name is the remaining path.

The `application.properties`

```
server.contextPath=/clear
server.port=8080
```

works fine if they are located in `src/main/resources` using maven's project structure.

Check log messages that should have the following line

```
INFO 4496 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/clear]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: The logs from both the Tomcat servers reads the same and the resources are in the resources folder. I have updated the original answer with these findings.

Comment: Can you use actions url in the config-browser page?

Comment: Checked, the config-browser page. For the embedded Tomcat. Actions in namespace / is all empty.
Whereas, for the external Tomcat, it shows up all the actions.

Comment: You don't have any action in the namespace `/`, how these come up in external Tomcat? Remove this attribute, use the default namespace, that is probably defined by convention with the plugin.

Comment: I also tried that, removing the @NameSpace annotation for / and keeping it to default. But it is still not showing up in the config plugin home page of embedded whereas it shows in the external Tomcat's.

Comment: I didn't see any namespace annotation, but I was talking about namespace attribute

Comment: I have tried commenting that in the struts.xml as well, but no luck.

Comment: Did you try out `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`? What is printed?

Comment: In the external tomcat , it is showing up as `http://localhost:8080/clear/`. But nothing comes up in the embedded version. It still says 
`There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/clear]` when I tries to access the root.

Comment: If you don't answer the question I can't help you, if you don't need it stop commenting here.

Comment: I should have made myself little more clear in the previous comment, not that I didn't try. The `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` value was `http://localhost:8080/clear/` in the external tomcat when I included that in one of the result pages, but in embedded tomcat version , I am not even able to invoke any pages including the root context (index.jsp)

Comment: The context path starts with `/` and it can't contain other parts of the URl i.e. protocol, hostname, port. So, it is not the expected value.

Comment: Good match, now you have to figure out why it was `[]` in the message posted in your question in bold.